# Reporting past events

Tags: grammar, reported-speech, sequence-of-tenses

Could anybody pick the correct alternative to report this event in the present?

**BOSTON and LONDON, July 20, 2020 (GLOBE NEWSWIRE) -- Orchard Therapeutics today announced that the company has received both orphan drug designation and rare pediatric disease designation from the U.S Food and Drug Administration (FDA) for OTL-203.**

**Alternative 1:**
On July 20, 2020, Orchard Therapeutics announced that it **had** received both orphan drug designation and rare pediatric disease designation from the U.S Food and Drug Administration (FDA) for OTL-203.

**Alternative 2:**
On July 20, 2020, Orchard Therapeutics announced that it **has had** received both orphan drug designation and rare pediatric disease designation from the U.S Food and Drug Administration (FDA) for OTL-203.

**Alternative 3:**
On July 20, 2020, Orchard Therapeutics announced that it **received** both orphan drug designation and rare pediatric disease designation from the U.S Food and Drug Administration (FDA) for OTL-203.

I am confused about if I can choose past perfect to report an event that had taken place before the date of the announcement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative 1** is correct for the reasons you explain. You have cast the announcement into the simple past. The **receipt** of the designations occurred prior to the announcement, so you have correctly cast it into the past perfect.

**Alternative 2** is incorrect for several reasons. First, the word **has** seems to cast the **receipt** of the designations into a past that is recent *relative to the time of your writing,* which is strange. Second, there is no tense that combines the present and past perfect markers **has had**.

This does not mean that the phrase **has had** is forbidden. Note the following:

> My mother has had Covid.
> My son has had his bicycle for 3 years.

In these cases, only **has** is a tense marker. **Had** is being used in its usual sense, meaning roughly, **to possess or experience.** We can paraphrase those statements like this:

> My mother has *experienced* Covid.
> My son has *possessed* his bicycle for 3 years.

**Alternative 3** is not as good as **Alternative 1,** and I cannot recommend its use in writing. However, the form is common in everyday speech. Many native speakers struggle to produce the perfect tenses correctly, although they can understand them when others use them.

Again, the word choice is not forbidden. There is at least one sense in which it works. For example,

> Orchard Therapeutics announced that it received shipments every Tuesday.

In this case, the simple past is used to describe a habitual behavior. This is not the intention in your own sentence.